# Trying to understand google analytics referrals

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out "automatic referrals" (without me providing the link)

I see some sources in the referrals section (Acquisition -> All traffic -> referrals) like t.co and bunch of weird websites I don't have any connection to them
Or some websites I do know that link to me but with no UTM or something (the link is "clean" to my landing page)

Having said all that - some sources I DO want to know if clicks came from - don't appear on the referral - and when I test it (and look at real time data to verify it's me) I get it as (direct)

I understand I can make a UTM but I'm trying to figure out why sometimes it works and sometimes not...

Comment: t.co is from twitter, it's their link shortner. The other websites could be referral spam (something that has been popping up more and more recently). [Here](https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam) is a good article on this. As far as other referrers, are you sure that you're actually coming from that domain? When you visit from there check in your dev console and see what `document.referrer` shows.

Comment: hmmm... you are right, The document.referrer is empty in the referred case. Post this as an answer - it is a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment I posted:

> t.co is from twitter, it's their link shortner. The other websites could be referral spam (something that has been popping up more and more recently). Here is a good article on this. As far as other referrers, are you sure that you're actually coming from that domain? When you visit from there check in your dev console and see what document.referrer

There are a few reasons that the referrer could be empty (coming from an app, secure page, etc.). Best way to check this sort of thing is to see what is passed on the page to Google's servers (Google's [debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) is a good starting place).